# Automatic pagination for status board program

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i have more data's in my mysql database. i want to display the data, per page 10 data only i need to display, for this i wrote pagination code. its working very fine but i want to run  that pagination automatically that means automatically after few seconds the page turns to second page then third page etc... but i don't know how to implement please help anyone. Here below the sample code for reference:

```
    <?php
include "config.inc";

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$r = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$numrows = $r[0];


$rowsperpage = 3;

$totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);


if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {

$currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
} else {

$currentpage = 1;
}


if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {

$currentpage = $totalpages;
} 
if ($currentpage < 1) {

$currentpage = 1;
} 


$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;


$sql = "SELECT * FROM test LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);


while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo $list['mark_cut_weld'] . " : " . $list['mark_cut_inves'] . "<br />";
} 


$range = 3;


if ($currentpage > 1) {

echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1'><<</a> ";

$prevpage = $currentpage - 1;

echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage'><</a> ";
} 


for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {

if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {

if ($x == $currentpage) {

 echo " [<b>$x</b>] ";

} else {

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x'>$x</a> ";
} 
} 
} 


if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {

$nextpage = $currentpage + 1;

echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage'>></a> ";

echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages'>>></a> ";
} 
?>
```

Above code, i just fetch the data from mysql database by php. then set the data per page is 3. i just get the total count and then divide by number of rows into rows per page... then automatically it will display the data.

My target is display the data from database. per page 10 data's and then automatically it move to next page for next 10 data without any action click or submit... 
    Because it is status board program..  we going to display by big tv in factory... so workers can see the status of the work in this big tv.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a header redirect to redirect to next page.

For example the following code will redirect you to next page in 10 seconds.

```
header('Refresh: 10; URL='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$next_page);
```

Make sure you set the header before you echo anything in PHP.

Comment: hi kavin, thank you. but i got this error after add your code at top of the page. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in D:\wamp\www\status_board\pagin.php on line 11

Comment: Hi user, i have update my code to correct the error. Please use that code instead.

Comment: thank you kavin.. where i need to add that line... if i add means i got notice error and URL will be like this: http://localhost/status_board/pagin.php?page=

Comment: ok kavin... its working fine but if its come to last page means its staying last page itself.. it should be run as a cycle...

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use javascript to [set timeouts](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) that will [redirect](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php) the location to the next page every so often.

For example, add this to the bottom of your HTML body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function switchPage(){
        window.location = "<?php echo $next_page?>"; // set the next page of results to view.
    }

    setTimeout(switchPage,60*1000); // call callback every minute
</script>
```

The variable `$next_page` will need to be a URL to the next set of results using PHP.

To have it repeat you will need a modulus on the PHP side that flips back to page 0 when the end of the results has been reached.

```
<?php
$next_page_count = ++$currentpage % $totalpages;
$next_page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?currentpage=' . $next_page_count;
```